# No module named pytest error in Google Cloud Build?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, pytest, google-cloud-build

My yaml in my git repo looks like this:

```
steps:
  - name: "docker.io/library/python:3.6"
    args: ["pip", "install", "-t", "/workspace/lib", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
steps:
  - name: python
    entrypoint: python
    args: ["-m", "pytest", "--junitxml=${SHORT_SHA}_test_log.xml"]
```

The build fails with this

```
docker.io/library/python:latest
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pytest
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "python" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

My requirements.txt contains the following:

```
pytest==6.1.0
```

I got this line of code from google console help so don't know why it doesn't work? [Here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-python)

Answer (score 1):

If you add `--user` to your pip install command, it will persist between steps.  See example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-samples/blob/main/python-example-flask/cloudbuild.yaml#L20)

Answer (score 0):

In your second step, can you try to specify the env var `PYTHONPATH` to tell to python binary where to look at the libraries. like that

```
steps:
  - name: python
    entrypoint: python
    args: ["-m", "pytest", "--junitxml=${SHORT_SHA}_test_log.xml"] 
    env: 
    - 'PYTHONPATH=/workspace/lib'
```

*I didn't try, let me know if it works. If not, I will delete this answer. it's juste more explainable than in a comment.*

Comment: I often struggle with pathing, but I entered exactly what you wrote as well as a few other tries, like  `- 'PYTHONPATH=/workspace/'` `- 'PYTHONPATH=/CloudBuildLearning/'` `- 'PYTHONPATH=/workspace'``- 'PYTHONPATH=/ClousBuildLearning'` 

Still getting the same error.
@guilaume-blaquiere